# How to force android's locationlistener to fetch provider location?

Tags: android, geolocation

I have written a small app that receives the location from mobile 3g/wifi by using locationManager & NETWORK_PROVIDER parameter.
according to google's api it will get the location i wish (the other option is using the GPS_PROVIDER)
what i really desired was the WIFI location. I wanted to see its behavior and how the phone gets its location (i.e with wireshark)
in order to do that, i changed into flight mode & activated wifi.
then, i launched the app and clicked the button which starts the NETWORK_PROVIDER location service by calling the requestLocationUpdates function with time parameter = 10.
what that actually happened is that i managed to get the location but saw no traffic at all in wireshark.
could it be that Google gives me the approx. location in advance, when connecting to the wifi? (its the only explenation)
If so, is it possible to clear that cache, or whatever data it have stored, and force the phone to get a new (but the same) location?

Thanks in advance,
Eran.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-booting the phone, just so to remove any cache files which might be storing the location?

Comment: It helped, the requestLocationUpdates didnt return any answer once I reboot my device on airplane mode

Comment: I guess there will be no data transfer(which could be seen in wireshark), as(according to my knowledge), Google must be maintaining some sort of listing of wifi networks and locations nearby them. A simple scan might give a list of available wi-fi networks, but that may not be enough for Google to tag a location to those available networks. Moreover, it may be possible that the wi-fi networks are only used as a refining measure after some coarse location is obtained from the network provider.

Answer (score 0):

Since NETWORK_PROVIDER use cell location, wifi ssid and their signal strength to get your GPS coordinates.

Since you are in flight mode and cannot get cell location, just try to switch the connected wifi , maybe google service will be invoked to get new location.

Comment: I tried rebooting the device, it does clears whatever cache stored. but i guess i have no way to see the exact packets responsible for wifi location..its just a part of the entire data that goes to my google account, in the same stream.. google didnt take the "lazy attitude", of "calculate it when you need it", they send me the location of myself even (if i may not need it) as a part of the entire data, all that while i just connect to my google account